# Reliable TCP transport for distributed clients

Tags: java, tcp, activemq-classic

I am working on a project where we have multiple GUI clients running on user desktops to a single server. The clients will be distributed globally and will be connected via a WAN.

I want to make sure that there are no dependencies on applications running on the client PC apart from the release package of the GUI itself. The transport itself should be reliable (no dropped messages, replaying unacknowledged messages).

I thought of writing a custom TCP socket based transport for our application and implementing some logic to detect dropped or unacknowledged messages.

I am also considering using ActiveMQ (using JMS via the TCP/IP transport).  Are there any other alternatives or suggestions?

Edit: TCP is a reliable transport, but I need to detect and replay messages that may have been dropped if a client disconnects or restarts.

Comment: TCP already handles the reliability issue. How is that not sufficient?

Comment: Hi Jan, it does not guarantee that if a client loses a network connection, it will be able to catch up with missed messages on re-connecting. Hence I am considering ActiveMQ. This offers a "late join" type function. I was wondering if there were any similar solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP guarantees delivery in a happy world where there are no application errors or crashes.

Some TCP data might get acknowledged by the network stack, but before it could be processed, the application might have crashed (or server crash).

ActiveMQ with transactions let's you handle those things. Even the application layer ack in AMQ will give you reliablitiy, with increased system complexity (of course).

Answer (score 0):

TCP [transmission control protocol] already handles all this.

It guarantees that either you'll get all your data and you'll get it in the correct order, or the sender is informed some data cannot be sent. All TCP packets contain their position in the stream, and the protocol sends an acknowledge for each packet it receives. If the sender does not receive an acknowledge, it resends all data the receiver may not have. Only after the receiver gets the data the application layer wants (always the next byte in the stream), it feeds the data to the application layer.

If the TCP connection cannot send or receive data (but not just because it does not receive any data), the TCP eventually gives up and you get an I/O exception on the sender side. If the receiver knows it should be receiving data (or it has data to send, or you enable keep-alive), it gives up too. You can adjust the amount of time until the TCP protocol gives up. The default value is more than enough.

If you want to know how much data was lost due to a disconnect (but the client is likely to not connect soon), you can send acknowledges on the application layer as well. If you get an I/O exception (and ONLY if you get an exception), store the last acknowledged message ID in a database and resume the transfer on reconnect.

If you do *not* want TCP to resend lost packets, use UDP instead. UDP only guarantees two things: what the receiver receives, the sender did send, and that it never attempts to deliver the same packet twice.

Comment: Jan, just adding to my comment above. I do not want to re-implement the an "message / ack" workflow at the application level if there are already similar sources available. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: Too many errors here. (1) TCP is not obliged to acknowledge every packet it receives. (2) "Only after the receiver gets the data ..., it feeds the data to the application layer" is essentially meaningless, as there is no other possibility. (3) TCP only gives up on a receive if you set a socket timeout. (4) The default read timeout is infinity, which is certainly 'more than enough', but I don't think it's what you meant to say. (5) "If you do not want TCP to resend lost packets, use UDP instead" is also meaningless. (6) UDP can deliver the same packet as many times as it likes, including zero.

Comment: (1) is the standard behavior of the sliding window protocol. "every valid data packet" should be acknowledged, otherwise TCP is not a sliding window protocol. (2) rules out out-of-order delivery, and that was the point (3) did I claim otherwise except by implying that receiver sometimes knows it should be receiving data? (4) The side that gives up is obviously the sender. (6) UDP will not actively try to resend a failed packet. True, the link layer may still mess up...

Comment: @JanDvorak (1) TCP does not acknowledge every packet. It acknowledges byte numbers. Your (2) only says that data is fed to the application after it is received, which is tautological. (3) You said TCP eventually gives up on 'send *or receive*": the latter is only true if a socket timeout was set; your parenthesis contradicts what it follows. (4) It is not 'obvious' which side gives up. (6) "UDP never attempts to deliver the packet twice" is ambiguous. I suggest that some rewording is clearly in order.

Comment: @EJP (1) It sends an acknowledge for every packet, that's what I meant. Additionally, it may acknowledge all data it has in the buffer, using SACK. (2) rewording needed? (3) explained in the next sentence. The parenthesis does not contradict the following sentence, it covers the default case only. (4) "which side" is specified in the rest of the paragraph. (6) I don't feel any ambiguity. Please suggest a rewording.